# Why NHST based A/B testing is not allowed to continuously monitor?

Tags: ab-test

I am reading a paper regarding A/B test continuous monitoring. https://alexdeng.github.io/public/files/continuousMonitoring.pdf

In the abstract part, it states

> A crucial problem of
> Null Hypothesis Statistical Testing (NHST), the backbone of A/B
> testing methodology, is that experimenters are not allowed to
> continuously monitor the results and make decisions in real
> time.

But without explain why this is the case.

So my question is: Why can't we run NHST based A/B testing continuously and make real time decision based on the result?

Answer (score 1):

Because that would lead immediately to data dredging. Imagine you have a sample and suppose you perform the test on the entire sample and get low effects, insignificant p-value and so on. If you would follow an iterative procedure in which you start with a single observation from the sample and while repeatedly add one occurrence you also perform a test, there are high chances to get a significant result at some point in time. Simply due to the randomness of the order of occurrences in the sample. The problem would be that you would do repeatedly a test with no correction for your criteria.